# How to do a SUMIF in Excel with the criteria from a cell that can be changed and if cell is blank, then just sum all

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a `SUMIF` with a criteria that can be inputted from another cell, something like this:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$D:$D,'Sheet1'!$B:$B,'Sheet2'!D$7,'Sheet1'!$C:$C,"Identity.Install",'Sheet2'!$A:$A, $M$9)
```

The `$M$9` is a cell that I want to be able to input crtieria and have this `SUMIF` return different results. However, if the `$M$9` is blank, then I would like to simply eliminate the criteria altogether.
 I imagine I would need some type of OR statement on this criteria, but would like some help in structuring it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `IF`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($M$9),SUM('Sheet1'!$D:$D),SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$D:$D,'Sheet1'!$B:$B,'Sheet2'!D$7,'Sheet1'!$C:$C,"Identity.Install",'Sheet2'!$A:$A, $M$9))
```

Comment: Nice, this one worked. The other one above, putting the If statement in the last criteria didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$D:$D,'Sheet1'!$B:$B,'Sheet2'!D$7,'Sheet1'!$C:$C,"Identity.Install",'Sheet2'!$A:$A, IF($M$9="","*",$M$9))
```